# Does/did for something you're continuing to do?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, past-vs-present, past-habitual

So the context is

> A: I play the piano every night before I go to bed.
>
> B: I thought I **was**/**am** the only one who **does**/**did** that

Because person B thought before that she was the only one who did it, but she's still doing it now. She still plays the piano before she goes to bed, so I am not sure whether I should use does/did? Or should I say

> "I thought I am the only one who does that."

Comment: _I thought I was the only one who did that_ is fine. The past verb-forms "thought" and "did" are not being used here solely to express a past time situation, but also a degree of modal remoteness (uncertainty) about the present situation as well. B is making a tentative statement; she is not entirely certain that she is the only one who plays the piano before going to bed, and the modal use of the past tense conveys that meaning. B could also say _I **think** I’m the only who **does** that_ where using the present tense makes a somewhat more confident assertion about her piano playing

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *I thought I was the only one who does that*.   This is indirect discourse that doesn't backshfit the verb in "who does that" to indicate an enduring aspect, something that has obtained, obtains now, and likely will continue to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

This is about tense. You're using the past tense of the verb 'think' therefore 'did' is appropriate.

> I *thought* I was the only one who *did* that.
>
> I *think* I am the only one who *does* that.

When taking into account the context of the original statement, and given you're using present tesnse, I would write:

> I play the piano every night before I go to bed, I think I am the only one who does that.
>
> **present tense** -
> a tense expressing an action that is currently going on or habitually performed, or a state that currently or generally exists.
> "I'm using the present tense"

Using past tense the sentence would read:

> I played the piano every night before I went to bed, I thought I was the only one that did that.
>
> **past tense** - a verb tense expressing activity, action state or being in the past.

Comment: The past forms "thought" and "did" have a modal meaning here, not a past time one. They express a situation that still obtains now. We often use the past tense in that way, cf. _If he loved her, he'd marry her_ where past form "loved" has nothing to do with past time, but expresses modal remoteness.

Comment: @BillJ This strikes me as wrong.  Modal remoteness relies on some form of irrealis -- either a condition contrary to fact or a wish.   This just looks like indirect discourse to me.

Comment: @deadrat Modal remoteness can be expressed by the use of the past tense: _If he **was** in love with her he'd marry her_ or with the more formal 'irrealis' (a mood form): _If he **were** in love with her he'd marry her_

Comment: @BillJ You still need the conditional.  That modern parlance is erasing the distinction in verb forms doesn't make the conditional not contrary to fact. There's none of that sense in *I thought*.

Comment: @deadrat In the OP's example, I see "thought" as a modal preterite enabling the verb in the subordinate clause to be backshifted to "did": _I **thought** I was the only one who **did** that_. Modal remoteness can encompass uncertainty.

Comment: @BillJ There's nothing wrong with *does that*.  Sure, backshifting is enabled, but not backshifting is appropriate for ongoing action.  In any case, the person at the time says *I think, "I am the only one who does that."* and then later reports *I thought that I was the only one who did that*.

Comment: @deadrat Well, I wouldn't use "does" with "thought" myself. But "thought" is undoubtedly a modal preterite which demonstrates a degree of uncertainty by the speaker, hence 'modal'. There's nothing amiss with then using "did" in the s/c, of course, but I think the sentence as a whole conveys a modal meaning. If the meaning was intended to be more assured then the speaker could simply say _I think I'm the only one who does that_, or if totally assured then _I am the only one who does that_ . Backshifting can be used for an ongoing situation: _Ed told me that he **was** blind in one eye_

Comment: You do ***not*** need to match the tenses in the two sentences. Requiring this strong tense-matching is ridiculous. If the speaker has just learned about somebody else who does it, then you have to use two different tenses. Most likely:  *I also play the piano every night before I go to bed. I thought I was the only one who did it*.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of it is that "playing the piano before bedtime" is either an **action** or a **characteristic**.

If it's an action, then it's in the past, eg last night.

If it's a characteristic, then we've still got that characteristic (like wearing a label saying "I play the piano before bed every night", along with your other labels like "I am a woman" or "I like jazz".), so we use the present tense.

Both are correct, and are just different ways of thinking about the statement.